# WooCommerce checkout error using cardsave gateway extension (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am having a problem when I am integrating the cardsave payment gateway to the WooCommerce plugin for WordPress

On the checkout page, I review my cart and select place order and the following error appears:

> {"result":"failure","messages":"
>
> ```
> \n\t\t\t
> Action failed. Please refresh the page and retry.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> First Name<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Last Name<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Address<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Town\/City<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Postcode<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Country<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Email Address<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Phone<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> First Name<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Last Name<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Address<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Town\/City<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Postcode<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Country<\/strong> is a required field.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Invalid shipping method.<\/li>\n\t\t\t
> Invalid payment method.<\/li>\n\t<\/ul>","refresh":"false"}
> ```

I tried adding a PayPal account which all works fine. The issue only occurs when I select the cardsave payment type.

Any help much appreciated